# Android - Why All variables, views declared on Activity is getting null in onRestart() method after screen unlock on Android OS 11?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-11, activity-lifecycle

I am trying to develop a application but I got stuck in a case that I mentioned below :

**1. I am in an Activity of my application.**

**2. My screen turned off (locked) after 5 min**

**3. I unlock mobile**

**4. After unlock, onRestart() method on Activity called and I have done some code on onRestart() method**

**5. But all variable and views on onRestart() is getting null when I debugged the app**

My code in onRestart() method.

```
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    try {

        if (new CommonUtils()
                .isConnectingToInternet(getApplicationContext()))
            new UpdatetoServerAsynk(getApplicationContext()).execute();

        GlobalData globalData = (GlobalData) getApplicationContext();
        CommonDomain serverLogin = globalData.getServercredentials();

        if (serverLogin == null || !serverLogin.Date.equals(new CommonUtils().getCurrentDate())) {
            new CommonUtils().forceLogout(this);
        }

        if (globalData.getUserdetails().TimeInOutFlag == GlobalData.PUNCHED_IN)
            mUsernameTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(GlobalData.GREEN));
        else
            mUsernameTextView.setTextColor(mColorStateList);

      
        new myAsync(HomescreenActivity.this).execute();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

All data is showing null even the views. I don't know why its all went to null. And its getting only in Android 11 OS. My target & Compiled SDK is 31. I checked whether it occur due to low memory and its not. Is anyone have this kind of problem while developing If so any solution or any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Can you post the code of the activity with the `onRestart` method?

Comment: I have updated the question with code I used in onRestart() method. As you seen on the code the value I have saved in global data application class is null and textview is null.

Comment: Is your `Activity` being restarted (ie: is Android killing the OS process and starting a new one)? Add logging in `onCreate()` of your `Activity` so you can see if the `Activity` is being killed/restarted.

Comment: I logged in onCreate method and its not coming. onRestart method is calling and values is null for variable and views. @DavidWasser

Comment: Please edit your question and show more code. Where are these variables and views declared and initialized? Show which variables are `null`. Also what is going on in your `Application` class?

Comment: Its an old application and have lot of code in that activity. Variables and views are declared publicly above onCreate method and initialized properly. This issue is only occur in Android OS 11 and rest of OS working fine. Application class have some static variable declaration, getter and setter also. @DavidWasser

Comment: Sorry. makes no sense at all. if variables are `null` this indicates that the `Activity` has been newly created. If that is the case, `onCreate()` should be called. I know of nothing on Android 11 that would do what you've described. You can add more logging and log the instance ID of the `Activity` to see if this has changed (ie: `this.hashCode()`)

Comment: I read a post about android 11 and they tells that on Android 11 Samsung will prevent apps work in background by default unless you exclude apps from battery optimizations. Is there any solution to this. i think problem is causing by this. any suggestions

Comment: There are a lot of devices that prevent apps running in the background unless they have been explicitly added (by the user) to a list of apps allowed to run in the background. There is no way to programatically get around this other than contacting the the manufacturer and getting them to put your app on a whitelist. However, this background restriction would not cause the problem that you claim to be seeing, as this only prevents services and broadcast receivers from being triggered if your app gets killed by the OS.